# Best Practice for running e2e tests of single page app using protractor/Selenium Remotely

Tags: selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to understand what is the best practice for running remote e2e tests written in Selenium - for running different suites on different environments. the testing code is attached to git and basically we use TeamCity, but it doesn't have ti be used.
any suggestions would be great
thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some best practices for structuring e2e tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050165/what-are-some-best-practices-for-structuring-e2e-tests)

Comment: thanks, but it's not the same. I forgot to mention that I'm searching for the best practice to do it remotely. just added that to the title.

Comment: It's the same theory behind it. Remotely or Locally, it will be the same. Please take a read of the answer.

Comment: could be, but that was not my question. the question is -should I create agent on TeamCity to run the tests? should I create a different vm dedicated for that? should I use Grunt plugin of TeamCity? should I use  Jenkins? we use TeamCity ios and cento - ios can't run internet explorer and cento can't run browsers (UI).... and what if I want to run it with parameters? I'm looking for the best practice of running protractor/Selenium tests (which can assumed to be already written) remotely..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my [protractor example project on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example). I'm not sure my examples would be considered *"best practices"* but it's how I currently do things :)

The examples cover:

- page objects
- Running on TravisCI
- Running tests on Sauce Labs and Browserstack
- Running multiple browsers at once

Comment: thanks, I will look at that. I keep hearing and reading those terms and names and there are a lot of them.